# Timeout XMLHttpRequest in QML

Tags: qt, xmlhttprequest, timeout, qml, qt5

How do I time out a XMLHttpRequest in QML? I have the following code, but it won't time out. It seems the timeout functionality is not implemented!? Is there any other way to achieve timeouts?

```js
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", "http://localhost/test.xml", true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')

http.timeout = 4000;
http.ontimeout = function () {
    console.log("timed out")
}

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        // Do something
    }
}

http.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Edit:**
The code is not in a qml, but in a js file. And it won't go into a qml file as it is part of the model (MVC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks that `QML` `XMLHttpRequest` does not support `timeout` function.
This is a list of supported subset of functions/properties:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest

But you can use `QML` `Timer` item for this purposes, for example:

```js
import QtQuick 2.3

Item {
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 400

    Text {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: response
        text: "Click me"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                response.text = "Loading...";

                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

                var timer = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.3; Timer {interval: 4000; repeat: false; running: true;}",root,"MyTimer");
                timer.triggered.connect(function(){
                    req.abort();
                    response.text = "timed out";
                });


                req.open("GET","http://google.com--",true); // correct me
                req.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if (req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && req.status == 200) {
                        response.text = req.getAllResponseHeaders();
                        timer.running = false;
                    }
                }

                req.send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about Timers. Problem is, that the code is in the model, which is a javascript file.

Comment: Regarding your code: Shouldn't the timer call `req.abort()`?

Comment: Ok, if we cannot use `XMLHttpRequest.timeout()` and also we cannot use `setTimeout()` we still can create `Timer` in `JS` and use it. I've updated my answer, please check it. I also took your remark with req.abort() in the code.

Answer (score 1):

A global **setTimeout()** and **setInterval()** utility that models the functionality found in browsers.

It can be used to indirectly timeout an XMLHttpRequest.  Or used sparingly elsewhere within the application.

```
timeoutId = util.timer.setTimeout(function() {}, 4500);
util.timer.clearInterval(timeoutId);
```

**Main QML Snippet**

With the following code, any child is able to access the methods under the *app.util.timer* namespace (or *util.timer* namespace if JS code is loaded in the main codebehind file).

```
import "CodeBehind.js" as CodeBehind

id: appWindow

QtObject {
     id: app
     property var util: CodeBehind.util
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    CodeBehind.util.timer.init(appWindow);
}
```

**CodeBehind JS Snippet**

```
var util = util || {};

Qt.include("qrc:/Util/Timer.js");
```

**Utility JS File**

```
var util = util || {};

/**
    Mimics the window.setTimeout() and window.setInterval() functionality
    found in browsers.

    @namespace timer
    @memberof util
*/
util.timer = new function() {
    var _timer;
    var _timerList = [];
    var _currentTime = 0;

    var _api = {};
    var _private = {};
    var _enums = {};



    /*************** Private ENUMS ***************/
    _enums.type = {
        timeout: 0,
        interval: 1
    };



    /*************** Public API Methods ***************/
    /**
        Mimics the window.setTimeout() functionality found in browsers.

        @param {function} callback
        @param {int} interval Milliseconds

        @public
        @memberof util.timer
    */
    _api.setTimeout = function(callback, interval) {
        var timer, id;
        id = parseInt(Math.random() * Date.now());
        timer = new Timer(id, callback, interval, _enums.type.timeout);
        _timerList.push({ id: id, timer: timer });
        return id;
    };


    /**
        Mimics the window.setInterval() functionality found in browsers.

        @param {function} callback
        @param {int} interval Milliseconds

        @public
        @memberof util.timer
    */
    _api.setInterval = function(callback, interval) {
        var timer, id;
        id = parseInt(Math.random() * Date.now());
        timer = new Timer(id, callback, interval, _enums.type.interval);
        _timerList.push({ id: id, timer: timer });
        return id;
    };


    /**
        Clears an interval or timout by the interval id that is returned
        when setTimeout() or setInterval() is called.

        @param {int} intervalId

        @public
        @memberof util.timer
    */
    _api.clearInterval = function(intervalId) {
        var idx, len, idxOfTimer;

        if (_timerList) {
            // Find the index of the timer
            len = _timerList.length;
            for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
                if (_timerList[idx].id === intervalId) {
                    idxOfTimer = idx;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Remove the timer from the array
            _timerList.splice(idxOfTimer, 1);
        }

        // If: There are no more timers in the timer list
        // Then: Stop the QML timer element
        if (!_timerList || _timerList.length === 0) {
            _private.stop();
        }
    };



    /*************** Private Helper Methods ***************/
    _private.start = function() {
        _timer.start();
    };

    _private.stop = function() {
        _timer.stop();
        _currentTime = 0;
    };

    _private.runInterval = function() {
        var idx, len, tempList;

        // Increment the current timer
        _currentTime++;

        if (_timerList) {
            // Create a temp list of timers
            tempList = [];
            len = _timerList.length;
            for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
                tempList.push(_timerList[idx].timer);
            }

            // Trigger each method
            len = tempList.length;
            for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
                tempList[idx].trigger();
            }
        }
    };



    /*************** Objects ***************/
    /**
        A timer object contains a trigger to check and see if it needs
        to run the callback.

        @param {int} id
        @param {function} callback
        @param {int} interval Milliseconds
        @param {enum} type type.interval | type.timeout

        @public
        @memberof util.timer
    */
    var Timer = function(id, callback, interval, type) {
        var _obj = {};

        _obj.api = {};
        _obj.hasRun = false;
        _obj.endTime = _currentTime + interval;

        _obj.api.trigger = function() {
            if (_currentTime >= _obj.endTime && !_api.hasRun) {
                _obj.hasRun = true;
                callback();

                if (type === _enums.type.interval) {
                    _obj.endTime += interval;
                    _api.hasRun = false;
                }
                else {
                    _api.clearInterval(id);
                }
            }
        };

        _private.start();

        return _obj.api;
    };


    /*************** Initialize ***************/
    _api.init = function(appWindow) {
        _timer = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.3; Timer { interval: 1; repeat: true; running: false;}", appWindow, "timer");
        _timer.triggered.connect(_private.runInterval);
    };


    return _api;
};
```