# XMLHttpRequest ontimeout not fired

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, qml

I wrote this simple javascript function based upon the documentation [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Example_using_a_timeout):

```
function request(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.ontimeout = function () {
        console.error("The request for " + url + " timed out."); // doesn't fire
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log("loaded!"); // doesn't fire
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) callback(xhr.responseText);
    };

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.timeout = 200;
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Usage:

```
request('http://192.168.1.105/test', function (data)
{
        console.log(data);
});
```

This code actually runs into a QML file in both Qt4.8.5 or Qt5.9.1.
Two odd things:

1. providing a correct url, the `onreadystatechange` fires, but `onload` doesn't
2. providing a wrong url (I mean without a listening server) the `ontimeout` event never fires

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: what is `onload`?

Comment: Is the event used in the example I linked

Comment: The links can be good to complement the question, but it is recommended that all the important parts of your question are in your post, because if the link is broken your question becomes unusable for the community

Comment: Got it. Edited.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598404/timeout-xmlhttprequest-in-qml